# Android cursor in RTL languages

Tags: android, layout, right-to-left, text-cursor

I have problem with android input cursor in RTL languages. When I am in RTL support layout, I have two input cursor and it's really funny.
Does it have real solution, for get rid of this?

I use this code to make my android UI RTL:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

And this my xml for text view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/myID"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="phone Number"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I may be because of you have set edittext gravity to center and cursor got confused. This should not happen but try left right gravity then may be problem not come. better you give gravity value start

Comment: @CreativeAndroid I did everything you said and still the same problem.

Comment: post your edittext xml

Comment: @CreativeAndroid I posted it, please check it out. Thanks

Comment: I think you forcefully setting it to RTL

Comment: @CreativeAndroid And what is your solution?

Comment: remove force RTL. if you want RTL then goto developer option and then try

Comment: did you solve this programmatically? Please share this solution. I'm having this issue

Comment: android:textDirection="anyRtl" 
workd for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem.
Just make the edit text language left to right and problem is solved.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/PhoneNoET"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:maxLength="11" 
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"/>
```

Add the above layoutDirection to your Edit Text and fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it using below..

In your xml layout, for edit text field add this-->

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

Here, "editText" is your view of edit text field. i.e,

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

Then programatically add text watcher for that edit text.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    editText.setSelection(s.length()); // this line is very important for setting cursor position
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping `android:inputType="phone"` instead of `android:inputType="number"` solved my issue.

Following snippet is from my xml :

```
<EditText
    android:hint="xyzz"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```